# How does Material UI TreeView recursive render works?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, treeview

I'm trying to render Material UI `TreeView` dynamically, so I want to add new nodes on the node expanding event. I tried to do that, but stuck with some strange behavior. I have a json data variable with some nodes, on the node expanding I'm adding some new child nodes to that variable and pass it to my render function, but unfortunately my tree doesn't change. If I add that extra nodes in another variable in advance and render that variable on node expand, the tree does change, I can't understand why, because at the time of passing that variables to the render function, the variables have the same data. Here is my example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-swanson-ld8nt?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Your function `addChildrenToParentByParentId` is mutating the `node` and `childNodes` variables.

Comment: Have you gotten this working with Material 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rule #1 of React is **don't mutate state**.  Here your `treeData` state is set to the `data` variable.  You mutate `data` by calling `addChildrenToParentByParentId` and then `setTreeData(data)`.  But `treeData` is already `data`.  They are references to the same object in memory.  So setting the state to itself won't trigger a re-render.  The *contents* of `data` are different because you mutated it, but React will not pick up on this because it expects you not to mutate state.

In order to do this properly you would need to return a new copy of `data`, which is honestly [extremely annoying](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns#updating-nested-objects) at four levels down.